# What is the order of groups in plot.survfit used for color or line types?

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I am writing a script that will generate plots of `plot(survfit(Surv(time, event)~factor))`.

The different survival curves will have a different color. How is the order of the color defined? is it `levels(factor)`? `unique(factor)`?

My point is that I would like to automatically script the legend labels and text. Can I safely I use `levels(factor)` as legend text?

I am sure this is documented somewhere but the help entry of `?plot.survfit` is not very helpful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the order of the color depends on `levels(factor)`, and yes, you can use `levels(factor)` for your legend text.

This applies everytime you are dealing with a factor. There is also a number of functions for you to manipulate the levels of your factor if you need so, e.g. check `?relevel`.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't this be somewhere documented in the help files,or am I missing something? Seems pretty important to me

Comment: Well, this is pretty standard for factors, so that's why they don't mention it in `?plot.survfit`. And you use the option `col=` to specify a vector of colors for each curve. The order of this must match the order of levels(factor).